# Java Rookie Rocket Scientist

Tags: java

I'm starting to learn Java. I have some experience with other languages. With some perseverance this will be the first of many questions. I'm looking for input methods for my Java applications.

The following code is the first example of the course book:

```
public static void main(String)[] args) {
    int num;
    System.out.println("Write a number: "); 
    num = Entrada.entero();
  }
}
```

It gives compiling error in "Entrada". I think it's waiting a Class, although there's no description of such class in the textbook I'm following.

Comment: I don't understand the question?

Comment: I'm not sure what Entrada is, but could you please post your entire code, including any import statement? Related, do you have something like `import something.something.something;` at the top of your file?

Comment: I'd say you need a different textbook.

Comment: Java does't have standard `Entrada` class which means you have to provide it. Take a look in your textbook if there is any example showing how to create such class. Also you would have to import it.

Comment: You're right - the compiler *is* expecting a class here.  If your textbook doesn't mention `Entrada`, other than including it in the code snippet, then the textbook is broken.  `Entrada` isn't a standard Java class or function - in this context, it would have to be something that you include as part of your program.

Comment: I might be completely off but if you're asking someone to `write a number` then you probably want to take an input. You  can do that with the Scanner class. Something like `Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);` And then `num = in.nextInt();`. Totally guessing here though.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'm really starting with Java and didn't see that at the end of the book there's an appendix with the class Entrada :) Cool community, I'll repeat ;)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `Entrada` was meant to be utility class to make it easier to capture input from the console (Java makes this task needlessly difficult compared to other languages). If the textbook is at all decent, it should have included the source (code) of this class somewhere (e.g. an attached CD).

Java classes can only be used if they are imported. There are only a few classes (e.g. from the `java.lang` package) which referenced and used without an explicit `import` statement. This is why the textbook should include the source of any utility classes they provide, as well as instructions on how to include them in your project.

You can get a simple program like that to work by writing the input capture yourself.

```
package testeroo;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int num;
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.println("Write a number:");

        // Read a number from input (not handling any errors that might occur)
        num = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

        // Echo the number back to the console
        System.out.println("You entered " + num);
    }

}
```

If you wanted to write a utility class for capturing integers, you could refactor (update) your code by writing such a class yourself (e.g. a static inner class, for classpath simplicity).

```
package testeroo;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {

    public static class Entrada {

        public static int entero() throws IOException {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            int num = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
            return num;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Write a number:");

        // Read a number from input (not handling any errors that might occur)
        int num = Entrada.entero();

        // Echo the number back to the console
        System.out.println("You entered " + num);
    }

}
```

But really, like the others said, you should find a book (or whatever) which doesn't run you into a brick wall in the first few pages. There are plenty of good Java resources out there. Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you so much :) That's precisely the point. The class was defined at the end of the book in a way very similar to the one you posted. Cool ;) Thank you a best of luck for you too!

Answer (score 0):

You will need a class called Entrada, and that class should have a static method called entreo(). It should look like this:

```
public class Entrada {
     public static int entero() {
     ...
     }
}
```

Try to look up your textbook and see if it offers such a class. Otherwise, you probably need to figureout what Entrada and entreo actually does.